# Scikit-image and central moments: what is the meaning?

Tags: python, image-processing, canopy, scikit-image

Looking for examples of how to use image processing tools to "describe" images and shapes of any sort, I have stumbled upon the [Scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.moments_central) `skimage.measure.moments_central(image, cr, cc, order=3)` function.

They give an example of how to use this function:

```
from skimage import measure #Package name in Enthought Canopy
import numpy as np

image = np.zeros((20, 20), dtype=np.double) #Square image of zeros
image[13:17, 13:17] = 1 #Adding a square of 1s
m = moments(image)
cr = m[0, 1] / m[0, 0] #Row of the centroid (x coordinate)
cc = m[1, 0] / m[0, 0] #Column of the centroid (y coordinate)

In[1]: moments_central(image, cr, cc)
Out[1]:
array([[ 16.,   0.,  20.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [ 20.,   0.,  25.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]])
```

**1) What do each of the values represent?** Since the (0,0) element is 16, I get this number corresponds to the area of the square of 1s, and therefore it is mu zero-zero. But how about the others?

**2) Is this always a symmetric matrix?**

**3) What are the values associated with the famous *second central moments*?**

Comment: I've filed an issue to improve the documentation: https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/2239

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array returned by `measure.moments_central` correspond to the formula of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment (section central moment). mu_00 corresponds indeed to the area of the object.

[image: Formula from Wikipedia (Image moment)]

The inertia matrix is not always symmetric, as shown by this example where the object is a rectangle instead of a square.

```
>>> image = np.zeros((20, 20), dtype=np.double) #Square image of zeros
>>> image[14:16, 13:17] = 1
>>> m = measure.moments(image)
>>> cr = m[0, 1] / m[0, 0]
>>> cc = m[1, 0] / m[0, 0]
>>> measure.moments_central(image, cr, cc)
array([[  8. ,   0. ,   2. ,   0. ],
       [  0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ],
       [ 10. ,   0. ,   2.5,   0. ],
       [  0. ,   0. ,   0. ,   0. ]])
```

As for second-order moments, they are mu_02, mu_11, and mu_20 (coefficients on the diagonal i + j = 1). The same Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment explains how to use second-order moments for computing the orientation of objects.

Comment: Thanks. Instead of having to refer to Wikipedia - which I have already done - I expected a little more information from the package itself. Thankfully an issue has been raised. So according to your answer, mu_02, mu_11, and mu_20 are, respectively, the last element in the first row and the first two in the second. Correct?

Comment: Of course the documentation of the package needs to be improved. mu_ij  is the element on the i_th line and j_th column (indexing starts from 0), so that mu_02 is the element on the 0th line and 2nd column (2 in my previous example), mu_11 the element on the first line and first column (0), etc.

Comment: I get these indices also have a meaning in the 2D Cartesian space (e.g., the first index refers to the x-axis, and the second to the y-axis). Correct?